# Sorting a std::list using iterators

Tags: c++, list, sorting, iterator

Is it possible to sort portion of a list (subset of a list) defined by iterators like `std::sort` does?

i.e with a `std::list` the only sort available is via a method (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/sort), I would like to be able to sort part of a list from its iterators using `std::sort`.
e.g

```
std::sort(listItrStart, listItrEnd, [](T& a, T& b){ return a.something() < b.something()});
```

I appreciate that iterators would become invalidated once a move operation is done on an item, which I assume means that a list cannot be sorted by iterators without re-iterating to the desired location before the next 'compare'?

In which case what is the best practice for sorting subsests of lists without populating another container for this process (if any)?

Many thanks.

Comment: I don't see a disadvantage in using `std::sort()`. From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort): type of dereferenced doesn't have to be copyable, which implies that no copying is involved. And time complexity is O(n*log(n)).

Comment: @Yksisarvinen - It requires a random access iterator, which `std::list` doesn't provide.

Comment: Ah, right. Silly mistake. Thanks

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Populating another container is unavoidable. But you don't have to move or copy any of your own data. You can use [`std::list::splice`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/splice) to extract and reinsert the nodes you want to process into sorted order.

```
using list_t = std::list<widget>;
void process(list_t& in, list_t::const_iterator begin, list_t::const_iterator end) {
  list_t sorter;
  sorter.splice(sorter.end(), in, begin, end);
  sorter.sort();
  in.splice(end, sorter);
}
```

The function transfers the nodes you wish to sort into the sorter list (the first iterator argument is the position before which the nodes are inserted, in this case the end of the list).

The sorter list is sorted (obviously), and then the sorted content is transferred back into the source list, exactly into the original sub-range it originally populated.

---

As commented by @T.C. The next step is to generalize it. It can be made into a template much like this one:

```
template<class List, class Compare = std::less<>>
void sort_subrange(List& in,
                   typename List::const_iterator begin,
                   typename List::const_iterator end,
                   Compare c = {}) {
  List sorter(in.get_allocator());
  sorter.splice(sorter.end(), in, begin, end);

  [[maybe_unused]] ScopeGuard sg([&]() { in.splice(end, sorter); }); 
  sorter.sort(std::move(c));
}
```

The comparator is taken as an argument here as well, and `sorter` is constructed with a copy of the input's allocator for maximum genericity. The splicing back is done in a scope guard of our choosing to support the case where the compare function throws, so our bases are now covered.

[Here is a live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fb44574dbbb07662), with a naive and somewhat silly implementation of a scope guard, for exposition purposes.

Comment: and splice take place at constant time.

Comment: @SaufenmitProgramming - Only the second call. Unfortunately the first one is linear. Though of course the complexity is dominated by the sorting function here.

Comment: Yes, I thought to mention it. I was also trying a soln with splice, but Best will be always first. Unfortunately, I have reached my daily vote limit and couldn't up :(

Comment: @SaufenmitProgramming - No worries. I'm always happy to get good feedback. Vote or no vote :)

Comment: `sorder.splice` thats `sorter.splice`, typo perhaps.

Comment: @SamerTufail - It was indeed

Comment: If you're going to copy them before you sort them, it would make more sense to copy them into a `vector`.  Sorting that will obviously be faster, unless the number of elements is very small.

Comment: @PaulSanders - This doesn't copy any user data. It splices list nodes. And the list sort itself doesn't do any copying either.

Comment: For more genericity you'd want to a) construct `sorter` with the input list's allocator and b) splice the nodes back if the sorting throws (which it can, e.g., from the comparator).

Comment: @T.C. - Will do. Making it a template is the next logical step.

Comment: Thankyou very much! This worked as I need it to :) and I have learnt something I probably should have learnt many a moon ago 0.o.

Comment: @lfgtm - Happy to help, I also incorporated T.C.'s comment in an edit, so check that out as well.

Comment: @StoryTeller I was thinking about the complexity of sorting a list.  But I see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/sort#Complexity) that, as for a vector, this is O (N log N) so implementations of list::sort must use something like a merge sort internally.  The random-access nature of a vector offers more flexibility in terms of what sort algorithms can be used though, so it is still likely to be faster.

Comment: @PaulSanders - It is the goto container indeed. But I don't think it's my place to question the OP's need for using a list, and as such impose a vector. Their data may not be move constructible, for instance. Or they may not wish to copy/move it for other reasons. So moving it into a vector and sorting is a non starter in this case.

Comment: @PaulSanders, actually yes, in this case I can use `std::vector` instead (Thanks!) and yes vectors are my goto hence I probably haven't come across the scenario of wanting to sort part of a list and put the sorted back into the original list before (I'm surprised, but hey this kinda thing has happned to me before ;)). I think there would certainly be cases (as described by @StoryTeller), also in my case here I have `std::shared_ptr<..>`'s as part of the contents of my list to sort. Would the reference counting add more overhead for a `std::vector` sort since it requires a copy?

Comment: @StoryTeller Ah, OK.  I understand the issue now, thank you.

Comment: @lgtfm `std::shared_ptr` is movable and move assignable (I just checked) so one would hope that no copies are necessary, but I wouldn't like to swear to that.

Comment: Test code for that assertion at [Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/4RuyzwplPIAOTVWe), by the way.

Comment: @PaulSanders Brilliant many thanks, My list can have 0 -> potentially tens of thousands of items :(, I'll stick with `std::list` sort and wait to profile before deciding otherwise. Cheers for your input. Much appreciated :)

Comment: @StoryTeller I can see I've got a lot to learn, you get my vote.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to sort portion of a list (subset of a list) defined by iterators like std::sort does?

I assume you meant std::list::sort. Visual Studio 2015's implementation does this, and without having to populate another container. It is a top down merge sort that is less efficient than the prior bottom up merge sort, but it avoids allocating memory that the prior version did since the prior version allocated a small array of lists. Psuedo code would look something like this:

```
    right = std::next(right, 1);   // right = end of sub-list
    size = std::distance(left, right);
    left = MyListSort(list, left, right, size);
    right = std::next(left, size-1);  // right = last element of sub-list
    // ...
    MyListSort(list, left, right, size)
    {
        if(size < 2)
            return left;
        mid = std::next(left, size/2);
        MyListSort(list, left, mid, size/2);
        MyListSort(list, mid, right, size-size/2);
        firstloop = true;
        newleft = left;
        while(true){
            if(*left <= *mid){
                if(++left == mid)
                    return newleft;
            } else {
                if(firstloop)
                    newleft = mid;
                list.splice(left, list, mid);
                if(++mid == right)
                    return newleft;
            }
            firstloop = false;
        }
    }
```